# Edit an object non-destructively in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to format the resulting object without destroying it. But all my efforts and research has failed me. Any tips are welcome.

My code looks like this:

```
Set-Location 'C:\Temp'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object FullName, Length
```

And what I get, is this:

```
FullName                       Length
--------                       ------
C:\Temp\CleanupScript.txt       10600
C:\Temp\Columns.csv              4214
C:\Temp\Content.html           271034
C:\Temp\Content.txt            271034
C:\Temp\DirSizes.csv               78
```

What I want is this:

```
FullName                       Length
--------                       ------
Temp\CleanupScript.txt          10600
Temp\Columns.csv                 4214
Temp\Content.html              271034
Temp\Content.txt               271034
Temp\DirSizes.csv                  78
```

When I tried this:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object FullName, Length | % { $_.FullName.Remove(0, 3) }
```

I got the right result, but I lost the Length column.

```
PS C:\Temp> $Files
Temp\CleanupScript.txt
Temp\Columns.csv
Temp\Content.html
Temp\Content.txt
Temp\DirSizes.csv
```

Please help.

Big thanks
Patrik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to construct the property you want in the `Select` command, such as:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -File | Select @{l='FullName';e={$_.FullName.Substring(3)}},Length
```

The format for this is a hashtable with two entries. The keys are lable (or name), and expression. You can shorten them to l (or n), and e. The label entry defines the name of the property you are constructing, and the expression defines the value.

If you want to retain all of the original methods and properties of the objects you should add a property to them rather than using calculated properties. You can do that with `Add-Member` as such:

```
$Files = GCI -File | %{Add-Member -inputobject $_ -notepropertyname 'ShortPath' -notepropertyvalue $_.FullName.Substring(3) -PassThru}
```

Then you can use that property by name like `$Files | FT ShortPath,Length -Auto`, while still retaining the ability to use the file's methods like `Copy()` and what not.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using a calculated property and `Split-Path -NoQualifier`; e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object `
  @{Name = "NameNoQualifier"; Expression = {Split-Path $_.FullName -NoQualifier}},
  Length
```

For help on calculated properties, see the help for `Select-Object`.

(Aside: To correct your terminology a bit, this is not modifying objects non-destructively but rather outputting new objects containing the properties you want formatted how you want them.)